# automated pdf print with embedded javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, printing

I would like to silently print different pages with embedded javascript in PDFs. I looked into adobe's JS guide. This is what i got:

```
pp = {
printerName: "BrotherA",
bUI: false,
bSilent: true,
nStart: 0,
nEnd: 2};

this.print(pp);

pp = {
printerName: "BrotherB",
bUI: false,
bSilent: true,
nStart: 3,
nEnd: 4};

this.print(pp);
```

Error message: "There was a problem reading this document (14)."

If i set the param bUI to true, or uncomment it, the code works. But then i got the UI, which i don't want to see.

Anyone some ideas? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This (strangely) appears to be possible - I don't want to copy the complete blog post this is explained in here - here is the link: http://blogs.adobe.com/acdc/2011/03/silent-print-in-acrobat-using-javascript.html

The essence seems to be that they request the printer parameters first and then only modify one field in it:

```
try
{
  // get the printer params
  var pp = this.getPrintParams();

  // don't show the print dialog window
  pp.interactive = pp.constants.interactionLevel.silent;
}
catch(err)
{
  app.alert("Error setting up printing parameters.\n\n" + err);
}
```

However, be aware that silently printing could considered to be a nuisance up to a security risk. See this security advisory from Adobe for example: http://www.adobe.com/support/security/bulletins/apsb08-13.html